# Ruby regex for whole number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Cant seem to figure out a regex to match any number that is in this format

`1.0` or `100.0`, basically anything that is a whole number.  Any ideas?

Comment: you mean this `^\d+\.\d+$`

Comment: 100.10 is not a whole number...

Comment: you need to harness the power of rubular.com

Comment: *whole* number, with optional trailing decimal with 0's.. `^\d+(\.0+)?$` should do it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
^\d+\.\d$
```

This will allow numbers with one decimal.

On the other hand, if you want to allow number without decimal too, you can use:

```
^\d+(\.\d)?$
```

And if for some reason you want to allow multiple decimals to above regex, you can use:

```
^\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

You can use something like this:

```
/^\d+\.\d$/ =~ '100.1'
or
/^\d+\.\d$/.match('100.1')
```

For more details about Ruby regex take a look at the **[documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html)**

Comment: how would I add that into ruby code to compare the numbers though.  Sorry for the noobish question.